# jQuery: Chopping up ajax'ed HTML an then injecting it into the DOM

Tags: jquery

I am loading some html from a remote source via the jQuery $.ajax() method.

Before I insert the html into the DOM, I want to chop it up into three pieces and insert each individual part into a particular area of my DOM.

For example, lets assume I load the following content via the $.ajax() function:

```
<div class='first'>First</div>
<div class='second'>Second</div>
<div class='third'>Third</div>
```

And want to insert it into this page connected to the DOM:

```
<div class='firstHome'>Some content I want replaced.</div>
<div class='secondHome'>More content to replace.</div>
<div class='thirdHome'>Final location for content.</div>
```

which would result in:

```
<div class='firstHome'><div class='first'>First</div></div>
<div class='secondHome'><div class='second'>Second</div></div>
<div class='thirdHome'><div class='third'>Third</div></div>
```

How can I achieve that with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the content out of the returned html and append it.

```
var $frag = $(returnedhtml);

$(".firstHome").html($frag.find(".first").addBack(".first"));
$(".secondHome").html($frag.find(".second").addBack(".second"));
$(".thirdHome").html($frag.find(".third").addBack(".third"));
```

The above code will only work in jQuery 1.9+, for previous versions, use this:

```
var $frag = $(returnedhtml);

$(".firstHome").html($frag.find(".first").andSelf().filter(".first"));
$(".secondHome").html($frag.find(".second").andSelf().filter(".second"));
$(".thirdHome").html($frag.find(".third").andSelf().filter(".third"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop should get the job done:

```
$(yourContent).each(function() {
    $("." + this.className + "Home").empty().append(this);
});
```